# Go: How to pass jsonb argument in a PG query?

Tags: postgresql, go

I wrote a PG query (a function) which takes in an argument (jsonb).

This works when I run the query through `pgAdmin`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM f_get_profiles(
    '[{"role": 1, "experience": 1 }]'::jsonb, 
    array[2]::int[],
    array[1]::int[],
    10, -- limit 
    0   -- skip 
)
```

And this returns me 3 records from the DB.

But I am unable to do the same using go code:

```golang
    q := `
        SELECT * FROM f_get_profiles(
            $1::jsonb, $2::int[], $3::int[], $4, $5
        )
    `
    rows, pgErr := p.db.Query(q, f.Expertise, pq.Array(f.Languages), pq.Array(excluded), limit, skip)
    if pgErr != nil {
        return nil, logAndReturnError(pgErr, "Unable to get profiles using the filters")
    }
```

The `go` types of arguments passed are:

```
f.Expertise : json.RawMessage
f.Languages : pq.Int32Array
```

I wonder what I am doing wrong. I am not getting any array but this is returning empty result.

---

More details on how I am accessing the rows:

```
var profiles dto.ProfileSuggestions = dto.ProfileSuggestions{}
for rows.Next() {
    var p dto.ProfileSuggestionsNode
    err := rows.Scan(&p.UserId, &p.Username, &p.Photo, &p.About, &p.Languages, &p.Expertise)

    if err!=nil{
        return nil, logAndReturnError(err, "Unable to scan the profile")
    }
    profiles = append(profiles, p)  
}
```

Comment: github.com/lib/pq maps json.RawMessage to jsonb without problems (also []byte). If you're using another driver clarify that in the question, please. In Go you are passing two more arguments than in pgadmin, so you are not technically calling the same function. Are you sure that has nothing to do with it?

Comment: @Peter My bad, just updated the pgAdmin query. Also, the drivers I am using  `"github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"` and `_ "github.com/lib/pq"`

Comment: @Peter Also updated how I am accessing the rows